# Libpq.dll invalid or corrupt file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, libpq

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I want to link my server project to a postgre database, I've downloaded the libpq.dll file from dll-files.com and linked it within the VS project, but when I run the project it I get the next error: LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2C0.
I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks and couldn't fix it.

Comment: Maybe the file is corrupt or you are mixing 32 and 64 bit. Also you should not download dll files from a site like this. They likely won't match the rest of the api. Instead you probably wanted to start here: [https://www.postgresql.org/download/](https://www.postgresql.org/download/)

Comment: You don't link DLLs you link with the DLL's associated export library. For the DLL in the question probably `libpq.lib`.